# TypeScript: conditionally cast an object

Tags: typescript

```js
type WithAvatar = {
  avatar: string;
};

type CommonContent = {
  name: string;
};

type CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar = CommonContent & {
  avatar?: string;
};

let withoutAvatar: CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar = {name: "Kevin"}
let withAvatar: CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar = {name: "Kevin", avatar: "foo"}

function needsAvatar(item: WithAvatar) {
    console.log(item.avatar)
}

if (withoutAvatar.avatar !== undefined) {
    needsAvatar(withoutAvatar)
}
if (withAvatar.avatar !== undefined) {
    needsAvatar(withAvatar)
}
```

Even though the code works completely as expected (it only logs one message), I am getting two errors from the TypeScript compiler: `Argument of type 'CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WithAvatar'`.

How can I conditionally cast an `CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar` item to be a `WithAvatar` item, IF the item's avatar isn't undefined? I know that in this case I can just force it like so:

```js
if (withoutAvatar.avatar !== undefined) {
    needsAvatar(withoutAvatar as WithAvatar)
}
if (withAvatar.avatar !== undefined) {
    needsAvatar(withAvatar as WithAvatar)
}
```

But that doesn't feel like a good idea. Like, if I add more fields to `WithAvatar` later on that might be optional in `CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar`, the compiler wouldn't do anything to help me make sure ALL the required properties are there:

```js
type WithAvatar = {
  avatar: string;
  anotherField: string;
};

type CommonContent = {
  name: string;
};

type CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar = CommonContent & {
  avatar?: string;
  anotherField?: string;
};

let withPartialAvatar: CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar = {name: "Kevin", avatar: "foo"}

function needsAvatar(item: WithAvatar) {
    console.log(item.anotherField)
}

if (withPartialAvatar.avatar !== undefined) {
    needsAvatar(withPartialAvatar as WithAvatar)
}
```

This logs `undefined` to the console, because we're not checking that all `WithAvatar` fields are accounted for. I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: There's a missing feature at [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) whereby type checks on object properties don't narrow the object itself (unless that object is of a discriminated union type, which is not happening in your code).  Until and unless this is implemented you could work around it either by writing a type predicate function or by spreading the checked property into a copy of the object, both shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mZXGDw).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an object `obj` of a type like `CommonContentWithMaybeAvatar` which is not a  [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), then unfortunately when you [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of one of its properties via a type guard like `obj.avatar !== undefined`, it only narrows the apparent type of that `obj.avatar` property.  It does *not* narrow the apparent type of the `obj` object itself:

```
if (obj.avatar !== undefined) {
    needsAvatar(obj); // error! 
    // Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
}
```

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) to support such narrowing.  Traditionally it hasn't been done because it would be "[too expensive](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384#issuecomment-761853522)" to synthesize new types for all objects up a chain (e.g., if you write `if (a.b.c.d.e.f !== undefined)` then you have a potentially large amount of work to do in transforming the original type of `a` to its new  apparent type).  For now it's not part of the language.

So until and unless that is implemented, you have to work around it.  One workaround is to write your own [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which tells the compiler how to do the narrowing you're doing. It could look like this:

```
function hasDefinedProp<T, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T, k: K
): obj is T & Required<Pick<T, K>> {
    return obj[k] !== undefined;
}
```

Now your check would look like

```
if (hasDefinedProp(obj, "avatar")) {
    needsAvatar(obj) // okay
}
```

Another workaround is to build a new object with the same properties as the old one, where `obj.avatar` is explicitly copied so the compiler is walked through the logic:

```
if (obj.avatar !== undefined) {
    needsAvatar({ ...obj, avatar: obj.avatar }); // okay
}
```

Personally I prefer the user-defined type guard since it is the closest to your original logic, but you might choose this spread-and-copy approach if you want the compiler to verify type safety completely on its own without taking some of that responsibility away from it (writing a type guard function is a form of this burden-shifting, since you could implement it completely wrong, like `return obj[k] === undefined` and it would not error).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgQQG4ENjoE5QLxQDeAUFGVOhltgFxQDOw2cAdgOYDcxAvl8aJCgBhAPYBbMSJaiWwCLPxFS5FujEQ6jZuy69i-cNFESpMubPhIAsuhAAjCGkw5FxydKnngUAGRLyFFQ4APyaTKycPHwAZgCuLADGwHBSUCwQEAAm9E7UABQIEGJ0lihB2ACU-uQJUvQiADYQAHQNImwFcmLNlM6VPPrETd4A7giIIrHAuTh0bqae8sClNvaO5YqEaWoaUABEANIQqKx7UNxDEKPjM7TC4u5mSyu2Dreb2+p0h8enADSBPrfaIiERnC7DKAiOwAKzmDwWsme41Wbw2BBsSGa2HQLEy4jyVQAPFAAAzNACsUGCUDGSEm0w2dDpZT6gzg0SgeWhMJ6GwAhHgCPFMhBoqwslUSAF0lkcuVubCKhwoAB6VVQCDYbAibD8qDKMjqqAAFUMUAA5FoIlAAD5QEViiWZC1QOD0NIibzoej0OBsVR2JpQYAiEPmq3hdgWgbEDlcxA+gAiTvSmQACjqwIqYQC9r1qHsKlLDWkMtlbjmqsaRABrWyx+M5vl9KCC4V41OS6pkWUVhVbZpDnkAguzKGwlvUc7KtUausNi76Y2xejQJDut0sRgQdCZKGczJwbAQJINEBQBKIU+1m2O8Vp4hxRLJVKJ+gph9ZTMiMBEk0AgcmoAB7mNkUC1hAIAiJyJoAHx5KWPJ0ABEF0AcxAVHQPJuh6Jq+FAABKEAAI6xMeWREumcAJLW-6AXBcE9lAJ7ALE2AsBOMIANq1gAum2QoOp2X6ZLogxAA)